# Crystal report Database logon failed using access db with password

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

I am using vb.net with access database with `password = admin` then i create some crystal report.
I can log on correctly in main report preview..
but when I try to load my report on crystalreportviewer ..
I get a database logon error. I entered correct password but still getting failed logon..  `

```
crystalReport41.SetDatabaseLogon("Admin", "admin")
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport41
CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()`
```

How to solve this issue ..Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the servername and db in your code. It should be like

```
myCrystalReprot.SetDatabaseLogon("myUsername", "myPassword","servername","dbname");
```

So if you are not giving then it cannot connect db and gives the error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226065(v=vs.80).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/create-crystal-report-step-by-step-using-sql-database-view/ (Search the "SetDatabaseLogon" string)

Comment: that is use MySQL.. I use Microsoft access for my database..  then how about servername?

Comment: check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381062/crystal-report-login-fail-for-access ,  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/748565/My-Crystal-reports-asks-for-database-login-while-l

Comment: what the error comes, are you follow the second link step by step

Comment: are you able to preview in crystal report without this login prompt

Comment: yeah I can preview on main report preview(not build in form (or usually press f5)) but I must enter jet database password.. sorry about my  english

Comment: if u have Visual studio n access please trying .. I really want know what wrong..

Comment: sorry @KhabibbMubarakk, but i do not have cr.